# Unity3D demo on iPhone cannot receive udp packets

Tags: iphone, udp, unity-game-engine

I wrote a udp send and receive unity3d plugin dll in c#, but it cannot receive any udp packets from server on iphone4s.

When server send a udp packet to the demo running on iphone4s, it cannot receive anything.

When server send a udp packet to the demo running on ipod touch 4, it works!Received the packet!

When server send a udp packet to the demo running in the Unity3d editor, it works ok!

I used Wireshark to capture the packets between client and server, it indeed captured the packet that server sent to the demo, but the client demo seems doesn't receive anythig.

Why?

```
internal class RudpNetInteractor
{
    private Socket socket;
    private EndPoint serverAddress;

    internal RudpNetInteractor(IPEndPoint serverAddress)
    {
        this.rudpClient = rudpClient;
        this.serverAddress = serverAddress;
    }

    internal void BuildConnection()
    {
        socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        socket.Connect(serverAddress);
        BeginReceive();
    }

    internal void Send(byte[] buffer)
    {
        socket.BeginSend(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnSend), null);
    }

    private void OnSend(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            socket.EndSend(ar);
        }
        catch {}
    }

    internal void Destroy()
    {
        socket.Close();
        socket = null;
    }

    private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            SocketReceiveInfo receiveInfo = (SocketReceiveInfo)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket receiveSocket = receiveInfo.ReceiveSocket;
            int len = receiveSocket.EndReceive(ar);
            if (len > 0)
            {
                byte[] dest = new byte[len];
                Array.Copy(receiveInfo.ReceiveBytes, dest, len);
                Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(dest));
            }
            BeginReceive();
        }
        catch {}
    }

    private void BeginReceive()
    {
        byte[] receiveBytes = new byte[576];
        SocketReceiveInfo info = new SocketReceiveInfo(receiveBytes, socket);
        socket.BeginReceiveFrom(receiveBytes, 0, receiveBytes.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref serverAddress, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), info);
    }
}

internal class SocketReceiveInfo
{
    private byte[] receiveBytes;
    private Socket receiveSocket;

    internal SocketReceiveInfo(byte[] receiveBytes, Socket receiveSocket)
    {
        this.receiveBytes = receiveBytes;
        this.receiveSocket = receiveSocket;
    }

    internal byte[] ReceiveBytes
    {
        get { return receiveBytes; }
    }

    internal Socket ReceiveSocket
    {
        get { return receiveSocket; }
    }
}
```

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Don't misuse it.

Comment: OK,Thank you! When i run the client demo on ipod touch 4, it can receive the packets from server. So strange!

Comment: ever figure this out?